# normally distributed, mean and standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Here's the question. Need to understand how to solve as opposed to just the answer that way I can be able to figure out how to answer the other questions myself! Thanks!

2. A person must score in the upper 2% of the population in an IV test to qualify for membership in Mensa. If the ID scores are normally distribute with a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15, what score must a person have to qualify for Mensa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the score on the IQ test. Then in the population $X \sim N(100,15^2)$.

You then have to solve equation
$$Pr(X>a)=0.02$$
where $a$ is the cut-off for the score.

Now,
$$Pr(X>a)=Pr\left(\frac{X-100}{15}>\frac{a-100}{15}\right) \\
=1-Pr\left(\frac{X-100}{15}<\frac{a-100}{15}\right) \\
= 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{a-100}{15}\right)$$

where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution.

We want 
$$ 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{a-100}{15}\right)=0.02 $$
So we solve the above equation for $a$:
$$ \Phi\left(\frac{a-100}{15}\right) = 0.98 \\
\frac{a-100}{15} = \Phi^{-1}(0.98 ) \\
a = 15 \Phi^{-1}(0.98 ) +100 $$
where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse CDF of the standard normal distribution.

Numerically, $a \approx 130.8$

Let me know if any of the above steps is unclear.

Comment: I get this, thanks! I was able to answer the next 3 on my own now thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Btw, please accept one of the answers to your question so that the question is not featured among "unanswered questions" any more.